# CakePHP 3 not saving hasOne associations

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two models - `Cars` and `CarOptions`

`Cars` hasOne `CarOptions`

If the user were to edit Cars - they can also set some CarOptions and save

Everything related to `Cars` saves just fine, but `CarOptions` does not save. If I were to debug the `Car` object just before save - I see the following

```
Car: {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Ford Mustang",
    "description": "some description",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "California",
    "country": "USA",
    "created": "2015-08-14T12:20:14-0500",
    "CarOptions": {
        "manual_transmission": "N"
    }
}
```

My code to save is as below

```
$car = $this->Cars->findByName('Ford Mustang')->first();
$car = $this->Cars->patchEntity($car, $this->request->data);
$carOptions = $this->Cars->CarOptions->newEntity();
$carOptions->manual_transmission = 'N';
$car->CarOptions = $carOptions;
$this->Cars->save($car);
```

However the CarOptions record is not created or edited. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not following the conventions properly, see

**[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Saving Data > Saving HasOne Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasone-associations)**

> When saving hasOne associations, the ORM expects a single nested entity at the singular, underscored version of the association name. [...]

So for an association named `CarOptions`, the property to use should be `car_option`.

Also note that if you want to let the user choose the option and its value, hard coding it like you're doing it isn't really the way to go, instead pass it properly in the request data, and let the marshaller do the "to entity" conversion when patching the entity.

See also

- **[Cookbook > ... ORM > Saving Data > Converting Request Data into Entities](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-request-data-into-entities)**
- **[Cookbook > ... ORM > Saving Data > Merging Request Data Into Entities](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#merging-request-data-into-entities)**
- **[Cookbook > ... ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together > HasOne Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasone-associations)**
- **[Cookbook > ... ORM > Entities > Mass Assignment](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#entities-mass-assignment)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Inputs for Associated Data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#associated-form-inputs)**

Comment: thanks - this worked. The hard coding was just for testing purposes